# Auto update legend without specific layer informations that still have to be displayed in the map

Tags: qgis, legend, mapping

I am creating a map and want to export it via the atlas feature.

In this map, I want to display certain symbols that I don't want to be displayed in the legend item. At the same time, I want to check the box "auto-update".

Can I hide layers "globally" to be not displayed in my legend?